# IoException and write in file

Tags: java

I'm not sure where's my mistake here.

```
public class TestFinalClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IoException {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Rockstar.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("file already exists");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

    output.print("Bob");
    output.println("100");
    output.print("Bibelo");
    output.println("33");

    output.close();

}

}
```

It's simply to write some data into a file and I get that error message from eclipse when I do:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

        at TestFinalClass.main(TestFinalClass.java:9)
```

Comment: `IOException` not `IoException`. What in the world is `IoException`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I just corrected the title. Why revert it back?

Comment: @Vite Because that's probably what OP is doing wrong. And don't use major tags in titles.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Is that one of the rules in SO to not use major tags in titles? I don't see the point. It's an IOException when opening file and that's what he wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.io.IoException` is not a valid exception class for catching `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

When compiled the following error occurs:

```
---------- Java Compile ----------
test.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IoException {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class IoException
  location: class test
1 error

Output completed (2 sec consumed) - Normal Termination
```

However, if you change `IoException` to `IOException`, the code will then compile.

Also, be sure to correctly import the desired class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at an explanation of [exceptions in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html).

The line:

`java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);`

potentially throws a `FileNotFoundException`, and you don't have any code that handles it (either by catching the exception, or having your main method declare that it throws `FileNotFoundException`).

This compiles for me:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class TestFinalClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Rockstar.txt");
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file already exists");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

        output.print("Marc Pelletier");
        output.println("100");
        output.print("Beshario Santos");
        output.println("33");

        output.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a try/catch block to handle the FileNotFoundException when opening a new file:

```
try {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Rockstar.txt");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Program run perfectly:
Just Give the correct url of file and make it IOException

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C://Eclipse Workspace//Common_Example//NewText1.txt");
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file already exists");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

        output.print("Marc Pelletier");
        output.println("100");
        output.print("Beshario Santos");
        output.println("33");

        output.close();

    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
       Marc Pelletier100
       Beshario Santos33
```